# Is it ok to reference two foreign keys when the primary key is in a different table?

Tags: mysql, database

Author(**AuthorID**, AuthorName, Address, TelephoneNo, *PublisherCode*)

Book (**BookID**, Name, ReleaseDate, Price, *AuthorID*)

Publisher(**PublisherID**, Name, Address, *AuthorID*)

**PK** = Bold

*FK* = Italic

I am trying to write a query which

> Will illustrate the books and their various Publishers and group by PublisherID

I get the general idea of retrieving this information but I would like to know if it is ok to references a FK to another FK.

For example `book.AuthorID = publisher.AuthorID` as the PK AuthorID is not in either of the tables in the query.

```
SELECT b.name. p.name
FROM Books b
INNER JOIN Publisher p ON b.authorID = p.publisherID
GROUP BY publisherID
```

Comment: You're not making a lot of sense. Why would the id of a publisher equal the id of an author? And note that in the absence of any aggregating functions, a `GROUP BY` clause is NEVER appropriate. For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Also, note that books can have multiple authors, and even multiple publishers.

Comment: And I cannot think of a scenario in which it would make sense to store an authorid in a publisher table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with "FK to another FK" you mean getting PublisherCode (book(authorID) -> Author(PublisherCode) -> Publisher).

I wouldn't do it cuz **Publisher** is a property of the book, not of the Author, therefore you should store the PublisherID reference in you Book table

```
Book (BookID, Name, ReleaseDate, Price, AuthorID, PublisherID)
```

Also if you store PublisherID within Book table, it will allow only one publisher, since the query you are required for is to show "the various Publishers" of each book, you should use another table to represent that interaction

```
BookXPublisher (BookFK, PublisherFK)
```

This table only have two Foreign Keys, and will store data like this

```
(1 , 1) BookID:1 && PublisherID:1
(1 , 2) BookID:1 && PublisherID:2
(3 , 1) BookID:3 && PublisherID:1
```

You can add another table for BookXAuthor to the same purpose

With that in mind you query will be

```
SELECT b.name. p.name
FROM Books b
INNER JOIN BookXPublisher bxp ON b.BookID = bxp.BookFK
INNER JOIN Publisher p ON p.PublisherID = bxp.PublisherFK
```

And your tables like this:
Book (**BookID**, Name, ReleaseDate, Price)
Publisher(**PublisherID**, Name, Address)
BookXPublisher (*BookFK*, *PublisherFK*)

Additionally, with `GROUP BY` you can count how many books have published a author o a Publisher